# Not able to access module directory

Tags: php, yii2

i generated one module which is for web services and module name is "service".

i added code in web.php

```
 'modules'=>[
        'service' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\service\service',
        ],
    ],
```

but i am not able to access this module in browser with below URL

> http://localhost/projectfoldername/service/login/index

```
service = Module [ dir : protected/modules/service/service.php]
login = Controller  [ dir : protected/modules/service/controllers/loginController.php]
index = action
```

below is loginController.php code

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\service\controllers;

class loginController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "test";
        exit();
       // return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

please help me if i am missing anything.

Comment: Which template you are using?

Comment: template means theme ? if yes then i am using adminlte theme.

Comment: Template mean `basic` template or `advanced` template in which way your application directory are organizied... and depend by your yii2 installation.

Comment: i used basic template

Answer (score 0):

Controllers directory where your *loginController* is, should be within module's directory.

> protected/modules/service/controllers/loginController.php

Comment: thanks for looking. sorry i was already did it. but in question i just forgot to wrote

Comment: there is no error. its just redirect to the root controller and said page not found